# syncing user data to username/password accounts

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage, amazon-cognito

I'm working on a new app where I would like to have users be able to register using an email address and password combination. I would like to be able to store a data structure on the authentication server. Up until now, I've always just created a PHP interface to a custom SQL database I would write. I'd like to move away from managing my own server for this project for various reason, and was looking into amazon web services and google cloud storage. There are quite a few options and approaches. Can someone that is familiar with cloud server technologies point out to me what the easiest route to achieve what I want is for each of the mentioned platforms, or others that I haven't? From my initial reading, Cognito seems to be what I'm looking for, but I haven't been able to nail down the proper setup for Developer authenticated users. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A detailed blog post covering developer authenticated identities is located [here](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en), covering a high level overview of the process, previous blogs with greater detail, and a link to an end to end sample.

Just to make sure it's clear, Cognito doesn't manage usernames and passwords for you. If you can provide your own authentication system, developer authenticated identities is a valid option, but Cognito doesn't do it itself. It instead leverages the logins from public providers (facebook/google/amazon), open id connect providers, or a developer authenticated identity to get credentials for accessing AWS resources.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up using Parse.com, and it seems to be able to do everything I'm looking for, and then some.